# Burp Suite - Use \n in repeater

Tags: burp-suite

Currently I am trying to fuzz the request I sent to Repeater. However if I put a new line (using Enter key) inside repeater's text window, burp on background really creates a `crlf`.

## My goal:

Send a request, which contains only a newline without carriage return.

### What I tried

I tried to use `\n` (as it is common in a lot of programming languages). However burp's Repeater treats `\n` as set of two characters - `\` and `n`.

[image: burp repeater]

### Question

Is there any way how to pass standalone newline character without carriage return inside Request stored in Repeater?

So far I tested this using my workaround in bash console, which is not-elegant at all:

```
curl https://mykey.example.com --header "Content-Length: 1" --header $'\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked'
```

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to remove the carriage returns in the hex tab?

Comment: Yes sure, but in hex tab you can only **replace** carriage return, you cannot simply delete it.

Comment: I mean, you could technically just delete a single character before the new line in the raw tab, then replace the hex data with the character you deleted...

Comment: maybe you could use multi-byte for example UTF-8 encoding of the newline character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @user, who led me to the correct answer - You must simply use hex tab, and then find carriage return character you want to delete. Afterwards just click the Right button and press `Delete Byte` option.

Comment: Once you have a line set up correctly, try copy-pasting it in the raw textbox. It might save the fact that you don't have a carriage return in the copied data, which would probably speed up the process of making new requests.